# Na Madeira, "desterrar" significa esbanjar - é uma expressão só de lá?

Tags: significado, etimologia, regionalismo

A palavra "desterrar" na Ilha da Madeira significa gastar tudo o que tem, esbanjar.
EX: "desterrei o dinheiro todo"

Essa palavra é usada em mais algum lugar com esse significado?

Comment: Porque achas que poderia ter esse significado diferente? Talvez tenhas algum exemplo de uso. Viste-a usada com esse significado? Alguém te disse?

Comment: Tentaste procurar num dicionário? O dicionário online Priberam [aponta isso como um regionalismo madeirense](https://dicionario.priberam.org/desterrar) informal.

Comment: Marcado como regionalismo

Comment: Por favor, procura no Priberam ou outro dicionário antes de fazer perguntas/ou adicionar a informação à pergunta.

Comment: @ClMend Editei tua postagem tentando focar na pergunta sobre se o regionalismo é exclusivo de Madeira. Entendo a crítica dos demais, mas geralmente fico feliz com tuas perguntas, porque o deficit de perguntas é o maior problema do site há muito tempo — contudo também é verdade que não devemos deixar nosso anseio por contribuir nos levar a diminuir a qualidade das postagens. Antes de perguntar é sempre bom ao menos checar as fontes mais óbvias, como dicionários e a Wikipédia. Obrigado!